# Why are some object properties UnaryExpression and others MemberExpression?

Tags: .net, linq, linq-expressions

Acting on the answer to my [Select a model property using a lambda and not a string property name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558974/select-a-model-property-using-a-lambda-and-not-a-string-property-name) question, wanting to add properties to a collection as follows:

```
var props = new ExportPropertyInfoCollection<JobCard>();
props.Include(model => model.BusinessInstallNumber).Title("Install No").Width(64).KeepZeroPadding(true);
props.Include(model => model.DeviceName).Title("Device").Width(70);
props.Include(model => model.DateRequested).Title("Request Date").Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}").Width(83);
```

I wrote the following code in the `Include` method:

```
public class PropertyCollection<T>
{
    public void Include(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
    {
        var memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (memberExpression != null)
        {
            var pes = new ExportPropertyInfoBuilder {Property = new ExportPropertyInfo {Property = memberExpression.Member as PropertyInfo}};
            Properties.Add(pes.Property.Property.Name, pes.Property);
            return pes;
    }
```

However, on running the code, I found some of the lambdas yielded **MemberExpression** values as expected, but others yielded **UnaryExpression** values.  I had to change the first line of code to the following before I could add all my properties using lambdas:

```
var memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression ?? ((UnaryExpression) expression.Body).Operand as MemberExpression;
```

All the properties are 'simple' types, i.e. string, DateTime, int, bool, etc. in a POCO business object.  They are decorated with several varying **DataAnnotations** attributes.

What causes some of the lambdas in my example to yield **MemberExpression** values and others **UnaryExpression** values?  In my example, the first **UnaryExpression** is on the third line, the **DateTime** property, but boolean properties also result in **UnaryExpressions**.

Comment: Does the UnaryExpression expression maybe occur in the presence (or 'unpresence') of nullable *columns*?

Comment: @leppie, I suspect it's on non-nullable columns.  In my example, the first UnaryExpression is on a DateTime, where the prior MemberExpressions are on strings.  A subsequent UnaryExpression is on a bool.

Comment: I will investigate a bit. I have used (or rather abused) expressions like this before, and never had problems, meaning it was always a `MemberExpression` else my code would fail. What version of .NET are you running on? I don't use .NET 4 yet.

Comment: Not sure if it will matter, but can you include the expected type of expression that `Include` expects? (including constraints)

Comment: @leppie, I've added the method 'header' with the expression parameter as best as I remember it.  I don'thave it with me.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12975373/expression-for-type-members-results-in-different-expressions-memberexpression

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I think I know what the problem is. Your expression returns type `object`.

If you change this to `Expression<Func<T, R>>` the return type should be correctly inferred, and `UnaryExpression` (which I will assume is some boxing operation) should not occur.

**Update:**

The signature for `Include` should be:

```
public void Include<T, R>(Expression<Func<T, R>> expression)
```

Comment: Excuse my stupidness here, but what should R be?  I can't make it MemberExpression, because the MemberExression is in the Body property of the expression.  I agree that the UnaryExpression is probably because of boxing though.

Comment: @ProfK: R is simply inferred, it will be the type of the property that is returned. You probably wont use it, but you might :)

Comment: I think I see what is happening.  Because the expression return type is object, it is boxed.  With a typed return type, this doesn't happen.  Thanks @leppie!  Trust a functional man to help out here :-)

Comment: Great answer.  Shouldn't the signature for Include be: public void Include<R>(Expression<Func<T, R>> expression) because T is already defined by the PropertyCollection class.

Comment: @Xcalibur: No, you have to specify (or define) all the generic type parameters used.

Comment: @leppie The T generic type parameter is already defined at the class level, so either a different type parameter name should be used if the intent is different or it is redundant