# Expression for Type members results in different Expressions (MemberExpression, UnaryExpression)

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, expression

### Description

I have a expression to point on a property of my type.
But it does not work for every property type. "Does not mean" means
it result in different expression types. I thought it will ever result in a
`MemberExpression` but this is not the case.

For `int` and `Guid` it results in a `UnaryExpression` and for `string`
in a `MemberExpression`.

I am a little confused ;)

### Some sample code

**My class**

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

**Test Code**

```
Person p = new Person { Age = 16, Name = "John" };

Expression<Func<Person, object>> expression1 = x => x.Age;
// expression1.Body = UnaryExpression;

Expression<Func<Person, object>> expression2 = x => x.Name;
// expression2.Body = MemberExpression;
```

### Question

How can i compare two expressions and check if they are mean
the same type and same property ?

## Update, Answer and complete Sample

Thanks to user **dasblinkenlight** who brought me on the right track.

He provided the method

```
private static MemberExpression GetMemberExpression<T>(
    Expression<Func<T,object>> exp
) {
    var member = expr.Body as MemberExpression;
    var unary = expr.Body as UnaryExpression;
    return member ?? (unary != null ? unary.Operand as MemberExpression : null);
}
```

I wrote the following extension method to compare the results of the `GetMemberExpression`
methods and check if `GetMemberExpression().Member.Name` are the same.

```
private static bool IsSameMember<T>(this Expression<Func<T, object>> expr1, Expression<Func<T, object>> expr2)
{
    var result1 = GetMemberExpression(expr1);
    var result2 = GetMemberExpression(expr2);

    if (result1 == null || result2 == null)
       return false;

    return result1.Member.Name == result2.Member.Name;
}
```

Answer (score 83, accepted):

The reason this happens is that `Age` is a *value* type. In order to coerce an expression returning a value type into `Func<Person,object>` the compiler needs to insert a [`Convert(expr, typeof(object))`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292051.aspx), a [`UnaryExpression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.unaryexpression.aspx).

For `string`s and other reference types, however, there is no need to box, so a "straight" member expression is returned.

If you would like to get to the `MemberExpression` inside the `UnaryExpression`, you can get its operand:

```
private static MemberExpression GetMemberExpression<T>(
    Expression<Func<T,object>> exp
) {
    var member = exp.Body as MemberExpression;
    var unary = exp.Body as UnaryExpression;
    return member ?? (unary != null ? unary.Operand as MemberExpression : null);
}
```

Comment: As for a workaround - could you use Expression<Func<Person, TResult>> and pass the type of the property you are returning? That way you wont need to convert it.

Comment: If you really want to blow minds, you can use C#6's new nullable property accessors to make this a (rather unreadable) one-liner: `MemberExpression member = ((exp.Body as UnaryExpression)?.Operand ?? exp.Body) as MemberExpression`

Answer (score 6):

Rather than comparing the `Member.Name` string, I would suggest comparing the `PropertyInfo` instances directly for equality, in order to avoid false positives when two properties in distinct classes share the same name.

```
public static bool IsSameProperty<TSourceA, TSourceB, TPropertyA, TPropertyB>(
    Expression<Func<TSourceA, TPropertyA>> expA,
    Expression<Func<TSourceB, TPropertyB>> expB)
{
    MemberExpression memExpA = expA.Body as MemberExpression;
    MemberExpression memExpB = expB.Body as MemberExpression;

    if (memExpA == null || memExpB == null)
        return false;

    PropertyInfo propA = memExpA.Member as PropertyInfo;
    PropertyInfo propB = memExpB.Member as PropertyInfo;

    if (propA == null || propB == null)
        return false;

    return propA.Equals(propB);
}
```

You can ensure that your lambda expression is compiled as a `MemberExpression` rather than a `UnaryExpression` simply by specifying the correct value type (rather than `object`) as the generic type `TResult` of your `Expression<Func<T, TResult>>` expression.

```
Expression<Func<Person, int>> expression1 = x => x.Age;
Expression<Func<Person, int>> expression2 = x => x.Age;
Expression<Func<Person, string>> expression3 = x => x.Name;

Console.WriteLine(IsSameProperty(expression1, expression2));   // True
Console.WriteLine(IsSameProperty(expression1, expression3));   // False
```