# Convert Expression<Func<TModel,Boolean?>> to Expression<Func<TModel,Boolean>>

Tags: c#, generics, lambda, expression-trees, expression

A method in ASP.NET MVC is expecting an expression `Expression<Func<TModel,Boolean>>` (shows a checkbox HTML control on screen), but my members are `Boolean?`.

In our case, for this specific situation, `null` is the same than `false`, a non-checked HTML checkbox must be shown.

How may I convert from `Expression<Func<TModel,Boolean?>>` to `Expression<Func<TModel,Boolean>>` adding something like `value = nullableValue.HasValue && nullableValue.Value` in the way?

Just remember, than the resultant `Expression` must still be a `MemberExpression`, what makes me wonder if this is even possible.

Cheers.

Comment: If you just want to give your nullable Boolean a default value, use the phrase `nullableValue ?? false`.  The `??` will use its value if it has one, and if not, use the value you specify.

Comment: Well, the app is not actually assigning values. It only uses the classes to generate HTML templates, but it is not using any instance of those classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are acccessing a value property (like `int`, `bool`, etc) you will not get `MemberExpression` but rather `UnaryExpression` as the underlying `MemberExpression` is wrapped in a `UnaryExpression` responsible for doing `Convert` operation.

This seems to be resulting from the fact that value types are not reference types and do not accept a `null` value.

If you would accept getting `UnaryExpression` you can do it in a following way:

```
Expression<Func<TModel, Boolean?>> source = ...

var resultBody = Expression.Convert(source.Body, typeof(Boolean));    
var result = Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, Boolean>>(resultBody, source.Parameters);
```

An stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12975373/expression-for-type-members-results-in-different-expressions-memberexpression) that you might find helpful.