# Get the property name of a property of an anonymous type from an expression

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, expression

The following code works fine for regular types:

```
    public static string GetPropertyName(this Expression<Func<object>> property)
    {
        MemberExpression member = property.Body as MemberExpression;
        PropertyInfo propInfo = member.Member as PropertyInfo;
        return propInfo.Name;
    }

    GetPropertyName(() => obj.MyProperty); //Returns "MyProperty"
```

However, if you pass it the property from an anonymous type, it throws a null reference exception because the expression body is a UnaryExpression instead of a MemberExpression.

How can I make this function work properly for anonymous types?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The expression body is a `UnaryExpression` not because of the anonymous type, but because the property is a value type that needs to be boxed as an `object` for your `Expression<Func<object>>`; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12975480/1149773).

You can avoid this by changing your method signature to take a generic type parameter:

```
public static string GetPropertyName<T>(this Expression<Func<T>> property)
```