# How to access property from lambda

Tags: c#, delegates, system.reflection

I'd want to refactor this code to get rid of relying on `TModel, TValue`

```
public static string DescriptionFor<TModel, TValue>(this IHtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
{
    // null checks

    DescriptionAttribute descriptionAttribute = null;
    if (expression.Body is MemberExpression memberExpression)
    {
        descriptionAttribute = memberExpression.Member
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false)
            .Cast<DescriptionAttribute>()
            .SingleOrDefault();
    }

    return descriptionAttribute?.Description ?? string.Empty;
}
```

which has invocation like that:

```
@Html.DescriptionFor(x => x.MyModel.MyOtherModel.Property)
```

to something like that

```
public static string DescriptionFor2<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression)
{
    if (expression == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(expression));

    if (!(expression.Body is MemberExpression memberExpression))
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    foreach (var property in typeof(T).GetProperties())
    {
        if (property == ((expression.Body as MemberExpression).Member as PropertyInfo))
        {
            var attr = property
                        .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false)
                        .Cast<DescriptionAttribute>()
                        .FirstOrDefault();

            return attr?.Description ?? string.Empty;
        }
    }

    return string.Empty;       
}
```

with invocation like that:

```
@MyHtml.DescriptionFor2<MyOtherModel>(x => x.MyProperty);
```

But here's error:

> Delegate 'Func' does not take 1 arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(MyHtml.DescriptionFor2<Test>((t) => t.StringMember));
    Console.WriteLine(MyHtml.DescriptionFor2<Test>((t) => t.BooleanMember));
    Console.WriteLine(MyHtml.DescriptionFor2<Test>((t) => t.IntegerMember));
}

public class Test
{
    [Description("This is a string member")]
    public string StringMember { get; set; }
    [Description("This is a boolean member")]
    public bool BooleanMember { get; set; }
    [Description("This is a integer member")]
    public int IntegerMember { get; set; }
}

public static class MyHtml
{
    public static string DescriptionFor2<T>(Expression<Func<T, dynamic>> expression)
    {
        var result = string.Empty;
        var member = GetMemberExpression(expression)?.Member?.Name;
        if (member != null)
        {
            var property = typeof(T).GetProperty(member);
            if (property != null)
            {
                var attr = property
                            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false)
                            .Cast<DescriptionAttribute>()
                            .FirstOrDefault();

                result = attr?.Description ?? string.Empty;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static MemberExpression GetMemberExpression<T>(Expression<Func<T, dynamic>> expression)
    {
        var member = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
        var unary = expression.Body as UnaryExpression;
        return member ?? (unary != null ? unary.Operand as MemberExpression : null);
    }
}

public class DescriptionAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public DescriptionAttribute(string description)
    {
        Description = description;
    }
}
```

It involves getting the body of the expression as a member and using its name to resolve the property on the object. The `dynamic` data type is used to get rid of the second type parameter, however you can also define it explicitly for better compile-time error catching:

```
public static string DescriptionFor2<T, U>(Expression<Func<T, U>> expression)
```

and calling it:

```
MyHtml.DescriptionFor2<Test, string>((t) => t.StringMember);
MyHtml.DescriptionFor2<Test, bool>((t) => t.BooleanMember);
MyHtml.DescriptionFor2<Test, int>((t) => t.IntegerMember);
```

EDIT: edited answer because initial solution did not work for value types, see [Expression for Type members results in different Expressions (MemberExpression, UnaryExpression)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12975373/expression-for-type-members-results-in-different-expressions-memberexpression)

Comment: I see you were already halfway there with your most recent edit... My answer still stands, the `Func` needs an input and an output type.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but for ``string property`` it worked fine, but for ``bool`` part ``(expression.Body as MemberExpression);`` is null - using dynamic approach

Comment: I found out that this does not work for value types, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12975373/expression-for-type-members-results-in-different-expressions-memberexpression for a solution.