# An interesting c# NullReferenceException

Tags: c#

I was getting a NullReferenceException in a web application and spent a huge deal of time to actually find the problem. I reproduced the problem with a console application. You can try to run the following code as it is –

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace Expression
{
    public struct ValueType { }
    public class ReferenceType { }
    public class MyClass
    {
        public ReferenceType ReferenceType { get; set; }
        public ValueType ValueType { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        public static string GetPropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
        {
            return (expression.Body as MemberExpression).Member.Name;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyClass c1 = new MyClass();
            MyClass c2 = new MyClass();

            Console.WriteLine(GetPropertyName<MyClass>(x => x.ReferenceType));
                // No Error


            Console.WriteLine(GetPropertyName<MyClass>(x => x.ValueType)); 
                // System.NullReferenceException
        }
    }
}
```

So the problem is the generic function GetPropertyName works when the expression given as the parameter of the function with the Reference Type property but The Value Type property causes `System.NullReferenceException` at `(expression.Body as MemberExpression).Member`.

> So my question is why it works for reference type and not value type?

Comment: I believe this can happen if "expression.Body" isn't of type "MemeberExpression."

Comment: @NexTerren it is a `UnarayExpression`, the question is, why?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I think it's a bit different.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3573250/15541 for why

Comment: @amit at the moment its not.  Once you do basic debugging of the problem and find the root cause of the NRE you could potentially turn it into a different question.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: That answers the question (key being boxing), but the way it is phrased, it seems the OP does not know how to debug, else it would be obvious.

Comment: @leppie you are right.

Comment: In summary of the duplicate, it is because your expression only accepts `object` as the return type, so the value type must be boxed and this results in a `UnarayExpression` of `Convert(x.ValueType)`, if you checked the `.Operand` of that expression you would find your `MemberExpression` you where looking for (or just let it take in a generic instead of object so it does not need to box).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to see `expression.Body as MemberExpression` is `null` for the second call, because `expression.Body` is of type `UnaryExpression` and not `MemberExpression`.

Why? The actual operation is "convert to `System.Object`". Conversion of a value type to a reference is known as boxing, and boxing is required if the delegate has to return `object`.

We can illustrate it on the following piece of CIL, which can be represented by the lambdas:

```
//x => x.ReferenceType
ldarg.0
callvirt instance class ReferenceType MyClass::get_ReferenceType()
ret
```

```
//x => x.ValueType
ldarg.0
callvirt instance class ReferenceType MyClass::get_ReferenceType()
box
ret
```

As you can see, the second function contains an additional `box` instruction doing what I've described above. The generated expression is similar to the CIL in the "convert" operation, essentially doing the boxing. If you try to create the same expression but without the conversion, it throws an exception.

Answer (score 1):

```
(expression.Body as MemberExpression).Member
```

If `expression.Body` can't be cast to `MemberExpression`, then the expression returns `null`. Trying to access the `Member` member then of course raises a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: I think the OP is more curious (or at least I am) why the struct decides to be a `UnarayExpression` instead of a `MemberExpression`.

Comment: I had not been clear before, my question is why it works for reference type and not value type?

Comment: @scott then he should have asked that instead of what he did ask.

Comment: @Servy you are right. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Your answer is right considering how i actually asked the question. sorry for the inconvenience.