# C# validation: IDataErrorInfo without hard-coded strings of property name?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

What's the best practice of implementing `IDataErrorInfo`? Is there anyway to implement it without hard-coded strings for property name?

Comment: This interface is used in Windows Forms data binding.  Getting property names (columns, really) isn't much of a problem there.  Are you sure you want to use it in a WPF project?

Comment: @Hans: yes, I think people are also using it for WPF: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63646/wpf-data-binding-and-validation-rules-best-practices/63754#63754

Answer (score 13):

#### A base class for common validation routines

You can use [DataAnnotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx) if you do some futzing in the `IDataErrorInfo` implementation. For example, here is a base view model that I use frequently (from Windows Forms, but you can extrapolate):

```
public class ViewModelBase : IDataErrorInfo, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public SynchronizationContext Context
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public bool HasErrors
    {
        get
        {
            return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Error);
        }
    }

    public string Error
    {
        get 
        {
            var type = this.GetType();
            var modelClassProperties = TypeDescriptor
                .GetProperties(type)
                .Cast();

            return
                (from modelProp in modelClassProperties
                    let error = this[modelProp.Name]
                    where !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(error)
                    select error)
                    .Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (acc, next) => acc.Append(" ").Append(next))
                    .ToString();
        }
    }

    public virtual string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            var type = this.GetType();
            var modelClassProperties = TypeDescriptor
                .GetProperties(type)
                .Cast();

            var errorText =
                (from modelProp in modelClassProperties
                    where modelProp.Name == columnName
                    from attribute in modelProp.Attributes.OfType()
                    from displayNameAttribute in modelProp.Attributes.OfType()
                    where !attribute.IsValid(modelProp.GetValue(this))
                    select attribute.FormatErrorMessage(displayNameAttribute == null ? modelProp.Name : displayNameAttribute.DisplayName))
                    .FirstOrDefault();

            return errorText;
        }
    }

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("propertyName");
        }

        if (!this.GetType().GetProperties().Any(x => x.Name == propertyName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(
                "The property name does not exist in this type.",
                "propertyName");
        }

        var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            if (this.Context != null)
            {
                this.Context.Post(obj => handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)), null);
            }
            else
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

An example usage:

```
public class LogOnViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    [DisplayName("User Name")]
    [Required]
    [MailAddress] // This is a custom DataAnnotation I wrote
    public string UserName
    {
        get
        {
                return this.userName;
        }
        set
        {
                this.userName = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("UserName");
        }
    }

    [DisplayName("Password")]
    [Required]
    public string Password
    {
        get; // etc
        set; // etc
    }
}
```

#### Taking advantage of IDataErrorInfo for one-off validation routines

To be honest, I end up using both annotations and the switch. I use the annotations for the simple validations, and if I have more complicated ones (such as "only validate this property if this other property is set"), then I will resort to the switch in an override of the `this[]` index. That pattern frequently looks like this (just a made up example, it doesn't have to make sense:

```
public override string this[string columnName]
{
    get
    {
        // Let the base implementation run the DataAnnotations validators
        var error = base[columnName];

        // If no error reported, run my custom one-off validations for this
        // view model here
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(error))
        {
            switch (columnName)
            {
                case "Password":
                    if (this.Password == "password")
                    {
                        error = "See an administrator before you can log in.";
                    }

                    break;
            }
        }

        return error;
    }
```

#### Some opinions

As for specifying property names as strings: you could do fancy thing with lambdas, but my honest advice is to **just get over it**. You might note that in my `ViewModelBase`, my little `NotifyPropertyChanged` helper does some reflection magic to make sure I haven't fat-fingered a property name--it helps me detect a data binding error quickly rather than run around for 20 minutes figuring out what I've missed.

Your application is going to have a spectrum of validation, from piddly things like "required" or "max length" down at the UI property level to "required only if something else is checked" at a different UI level and all the way up to "username does not exist" in the domain/persistence level. You will find that you will have to make trade-offs between repeating a little validation logic in the UI versus adding lots of metadata in the domain to describe itself to the UI, and you'll have to make trade-offs as to how these different classes of validation errors are displayed to the user.

Hope that helps. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks very much. A not-related question: could you please give me some background on why we need `SynchronizationContext` and how it should be used? I'm not very familiar with concurrency programming but curious about that. :)

Comment: WPF and Windows Forms controls and elements are not thread-safe. This means that when you interact with them, you need to be on the same thread that they were created on, a thread with a message pump. If you fire off to do some work in a background thread, and then touch one of these INotifyPropertyChanged properties of a view model, then the event will fire and the control will try to update itself as a result of an event on the wrong thread. The Windows Forms implementation of SynchronizationContext allows us to marshal that callback to the correct thread. If confused, leave it out.

Comment: For WPF you should be using Dispatcher instead of SynchronizationContext.

Comment: +1 for using "fat-fingered".  I'm totally going to add that to my base classes!

Answer (score 2):

You may find some use in the accepted answer to my question, [Select a model property using a lambda and not a string property name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558974/select-a-model-property-using-a-lambda-and-not-a-string-property-name), specifically only for specifying properties without using strings.  I'm afraid I can't help directly with implementing `IDataErrorInfo`.

Answer (score 0):

For this situation (and `INotifyPropertyChanged`) I tend to go with a private static class declaring all the property names as constants:

```
public class Customer : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo, etc
{
  private static class Properties
  {
    public const string Email = "Email";
    public const string FirstName = "FirstName";
  }  


}
```

There's still a little repetition but it's worked fine for me on a few projects.

As for organizing the validation... You could consider a separate CustomerValidator class to be supplied at run-time. You can then swap different implementations for different contexts. So, for example, new customers could be validated differently to existing ones without a mess of conditionals.